# Can't find out where does a node.js app running and can't kill it

Tags: linux, node.js

**What I did:**
I have just set up node environment, installed express, create and installed an express project

```
express hello
cd hello && npm install
```

then started the app with "`node app`".

**Environment:**

```
yole@Yole:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.2 (wheezy)
Release:    7.2
Codename:   wheezy

yole@Yole:~$ node --version
v0.10.22

yole@Yole:~$ express --version
3.4.4
```

**Problem**
When I want to stop this app, I used `CTRL+C,` but the thing I found is it did not stopped. Then I restarted the server! I found I can still access the page in browser. Orz.

I have tried the following thing but still can't find out the running process.

```
yole@Yole:~$ killall node
node: no process found

yole@Yole:~$ ps -ef|grep node
yole      3161  2888  0 16:57 pts/1    00:00:00 grep node

yole@Yole:~$ netstat -apn|grep 3000
```

**Question**
How to find out the running node process or how to kill it.

=====
**update**
It is very strange that all browses in my machine can visit the site while it's not available on other machine! I only visit the page with Chrome before I stop the application. It seems to be a cache problem, but how cache shared among browsers..

Comment: The node process isn't running, as shown by the output of `ps`. Your browser must serve a cached version of your website: try after clearing its cache.

Comment: @PaulMougel I have changed to another browser

Comment: Are you running it on actual hardware or in a VM?

Comment: @robertklep I am running the app on a VPS server.

Comment: @yuyue007 I had a similar issue recently with Vagrant (not a VPS though, but a locally running VirtualBox), where a previous VM wasn't properly shut down and there were two instances running, *both* of which were answering my requests. If your VPS provider supports it, shut down the VPS instead of 'just' rebooting it. Also, make sure there isn't some form of caching server in between you and your provider.

Comment: @robertklep I have shut down the VPS at provider is control panel and I have also reboot my computer, but the I still can see the page. I don't think there is any cache server. When I shut down VPS, I can't load the page, when VPS start again, the page is available again, so something must be wrong between VPS.

Answer (score 116):

List node process:

```
$ ps -e|grep node
```

Kill the process using

```
$kill -9 XXXX
```

Here XXXX is the process number

Comment: there is no node process found by ps command, I have pasted the result above.

Comment: How you are starting node application?

Comment: I did not start node application after I restart server. But I can visit the node app with browser, strange things.

Comment: Clear cache in your browser and check

Comment: actually I have switched several browsers, still can see the page.

Answer (score 72):

If you want know, the how may nodejs processes running then you can use this command

```
ps -aef | grep node
```

So it will give list of nodejs process with it's project name. It will be helpful when you are running multipe nodejs application & you want kill specific process for the specific project.

Above command will give output like

```
XXX  12886  1741  1 12:36 ?        00:00:05 /home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/bin/node --inspect-brk=43443 /node application running path.
```

So to kill you can use following command

```
kill -9 12886
```

So it will kill the spcefic node process

Comment: I like it because it gives a full path to the node and executed scripts.

Answer (score 15):

You can kill all node processes using `pkill node`

or you can do a `ps T` to see all processes on this terminal
then you can kill a specific process ID doing a `kill [processID]` example: `kill 24491`

Additionally, you can do a `ps -help` to see all the available options

Comment: `pkill node` saved me a lot of time

Comment: gitlab-runner: `$ pkill node` ERROR: Job failed

Comment: @Geo I think this is a problem with Gitlab, rather than the linux pkill command. A quick search yielded issues in Gitlab.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer I figured it out. The problem actually was in the way the process that I am pkilling *was started*. The output upon exit (pkill) *was not suppressed* in advance, so when being killed - it throws, which in turn breaks the gitlab job. The solution is to start the node process silently: `(npm start &) > /dev/null 2>&1`, which then when pkilled dies quitely. +1! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Coming to this from a macOS - investigating with these 3 commands are often helpful:

replace 6006 with a meaningful port of your apps URL, in my case I was hunting for localhost:6006 which was not a running app but still available when hitting the URL in browser.

**Netstat**

`netstat -anp tcp | grep 6006`

This will report the type of connection and command that is running it, from here you can investigate the TCP states:

```
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.58473        127.0.0.1.6006         CLOSE_WAIT
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.6006         127.0.0.1.58471        FIN_WAIT_2
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.58471        127.0.0.1.6006         CLOSE_WAIT
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.6006         *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.58468        127.0.0.1.6006         TIME_WAIT
```

**lsof**

`lsof -i tcp:6006`

This will list the command name and PID.

Optionally after this, you can use `kill` along with the PID number to stop the processes from running. ex: `kill #####`

```
COMMAND     PID       USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node       8193 username   26u  IPv4 0x8793aae78e568e01      0t0  TCP localhost:6006 (LISTEN)
Google    93430 username   67u  IPv4 0x8793aae79530c941      0t0  TCP localhost:58471->localhost:6006 (CLOSE_WAIT)
Google    93430 username   68u  IPv4 0x8793aae795d98ba1      0t0  TCP localhost:58473->localhost:6006 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

Finally to find where the `node` process is running you can use `ps` and here, instead of using `node` as others have mentioned use the port number itself that you are looking for:

**ps**

`ps -aef | grep 6006`

This will report back something like this:

```
  501  8193  8179   0 24May21 ttys008    1:08.98 /Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v12.10.0/bin/node /Users/username/Documents/repositories/react-application/node_modules/.bin/start-storybook -h localhost -p 6006
  501 77757  9725   0 12:50PM ttys013    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox 6006
```

Now we can confirm the PID from our `lsof` command matches the PID printed by the `ps`, we can see when the process was started and we are seeing the path to our persistent app.

Lastly we can use `kill ####` to stop the process.

Answer (score 5):

I use **fkill**

**INSTALL**

```
npm i fkill-cli -g
```

**EXAMPLES**

*Search process in command line*

```
fkill
```

*OR: kill ! ALL process*

```
fkill node
```

*OR: kill process using port 8080*

```
fkill :8080
```

Answer (score 2):

If all those kill process commands don't work for you, my suggestion is to check if you were using any other packages to run your node process.

I had the similar issue, and it was due to I was running my node process using PM2(a NPM package). The `kill [processID]` command disables the process but keeps the port occupied. Hence I had to go into PM2 and dump all node process to free up the port again.