# Can't kill node app on nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm running a small node (via express) server on Ubuntu 14 with nginx and PM2. I ran `pm2` stop, restarted my nginx server, but the app still runs. Is there something else I need to restart/kill? I've even killed nginx all together, checked that it did indeed stop, then restarted it, and the app still shows up running.

`pm2` list/stop:

```
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬─────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory │ watching │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴─────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴────────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app

$ pm2 stop all
[PM2][WARN] No process found
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬─────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory │ watching │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴─────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴────────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app


$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

$ sudo service nginx restart
 * Restarting nginx nginx                                                                                                                                                                            [ OK ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Found this post [Can't find out where does a node.js app running and can't kill it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091433/cant-find-out-where-does-a-node-js-app-running-and-cant-kill-it), that led me to:

```
$ ps -e|grep node

$kill -9 XXXX
```

I'm still curious why PM2 doesn't show the process? I definitely used it to start the app.