# I get throw new ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN(); when I try to run my program with node.js. Am I closing it wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

recently I have been using node.js to code something that creates a server on localhost, and when I'm done running it with node, I press control+C to stop it. Then I made some modifications, attempted to run it again, and I get this:

```
net.js:1399
    throw new ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN();
    ^

Error [ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN]: Listen method has been called more than once without closing.
    at Server.listen (net.js:1399:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mmein\OneDrive\Desktop\pywork\socketthing.js:16:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN'
}
```

Did I close my program wrong and its still running in the background? If so, how do I close it?
Thanks in advance if you help.

Comment: Maybe you started the server wrong and `ctrl-c` closed  something else. Who knows? In windows, say, did you check the task manager to see if the server is still running?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find out where does a node.js app running and can't kill it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091433/cant-find-out-where-does-a-node-js-app-running-and-cant-kill-it)